# How to not update columns in Sequelize v6 if they have not been changed in the incoming data?

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

In version 5 I could do this

```
const data = {
  userId: 1,
  login: 'admin',
};
const { userId, ...userData } = data;
const candidate = await findById(userId);
const record = await candidate.update({ ...userData });
return record;
```

If the user already had an "admin" login, then the update request was not executed.
Now I have updated to 6 versions, and this feature is gone. Whatever data I place, the update request is executed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you stumbled upon this question like I did, then having studied the updates in version 6, I unfortunately did not find anything about it :(
But for that they added a check for fields to the "changed" function.

```
const instance = await MyModel.findOne();

instance.myJsonField.someProperty = 12345; // Changed from something else to 12345
console.log(instance.changed()); // false

await instance.save(); // this will not save anything

instance.changed("myJsonField", true);
console.log(instance.changed()); // ['myJsonField']

await instance.save(); // will save
```

That is, the data will not be updated if the object is exactly the same as the columns in the database.